# Android WebView + WebGL + Camera: BufferQueue has been abandoned

Tags: javascript, android, webview, camera, webgl

I am writing application with augmented reality using webGL and android WebView (chrome 54.0). That's how I get video stream in JS application (and that works just fine):

```
return navigator
        .mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({video: {
            "facingMode": "environment",
            "width": cameraWidth,
            "height": cameraHeight
        }})
        .then((stream) => {
            let cameraURL = URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            // create Three.js texture with updated camera picture
        })
        .catch(function(exception) {
            // ...
        });
```

And I have to show some UI view's in my webview, so I capture bitmap from view and upload it to JS application:

```
Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        myView.getMeasuredWidth(),
        myView.getMeasuredHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
myView.draw(canvas);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
viewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteStream);
String base64EncodedBitmap = "data:image/png;base64," 
        + Base64.encodeToString(
              byteStream.toByteArray(),
              Base64.DEFAULT
          );

mWebView.loadUrl(
    String.format(
        "javascript:someFunction(\"%s\");void(0);",
        base64EncodedBitmap
    )
);
```

That works on my device, Huawei P8 Lite (6.0), but fails on Nexus 5 (6.0.1) - after loading some views (and probably after garbage collector's work) it freezes video from camera and continiously repeats in log:

```
E/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-7366-1] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

Does anyone know, what is going wrong, and how to solve this problem?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't find correct solution. Finally I ended up with WebView with transparent background placed over the Android TextureView showing video from camera.